# Is html5 video tag not support on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

html5 video tag doesn't work on mobile. I use below code. How can I run my viedo on mobile. I used html5 video tag.

```
<video id="vid1" autoplay loop >

 <source src="viedos/viedo.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
 <source src="viedos/viedo.ogg" type="video/ogg" >

 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: For a start, you should check your spelling. Chances are it's looking for a file that doesn't exist

Comment: Downvoted for laziness. You could just googled it. I recommend looking at http://caniuse.com All right, [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video)

Comment: Autoplay won't work on mobile.

Comment: @SteveMuster no need to upvote

Comment: Does your site work on desktop?

Comment: yes my site is working on desktop

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 video tag is supported on several mobile browsers. See [here](http://caniuse.com/video) for which ones.